# TYPFontAwesome 4.1.0 not being loaded (using pods)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6, font-awesome

I have an ios project that I want to use FontAwesome icons in and I am having some troubles.  I loaded the TypFontAwesome pod and I can see the font in the interface builder, but I can't access it in code.  I do a dump of the font families and I do not see FontAwesome loaded.

I was thinking that I should be able to say:

```
[myButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"FontAwesome" size: 18]];
```

But all I see are unicode symbols instead of the icons.

Why is the font loaded into the interface builder and not available in code?  Do I need to import it somewhere, or make the app aware of it somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it..

I thought that the fonts would automatically be added to the plist file because I installed the using a pod.  Turns out that that was not the case.  Adding the font to the plist file resolved my issue.